# Getting the value of attribute data-* in an inline function

Tags: javascript

I have a data attribute `data-niq` which i am using to store some data. I want to pass the data in `*-niq` to a function as a second parameter to a function.

This is the code

```
<button onClick="editevent(this.id,this.id.getAttribute('data-niq'));" id="mid" data-niq="niq" class="mr edit btn btn-success pull-right"> Edit</button>

<script>
function editevent(clicked_id,attri_bute){
console.log('clicked id',clicked_id);
console.log('data-niq',attri_bute);
}
</script>
```

and the link https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/zob8dm4z/8/

When i run the code i get `TypeError: this.id.getAttribute is not a function`

How can i pass the `data-niq` value in the inline function that i am calling?.

Comment: The answer is quite simple, stop using inline javascript

Comment: get rid of the `.id` in `this.id.getAttribute('data-niq')`. however i'd also suggest you to stop using inline javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things here

1. Never mix your mark up with javascript
2. Try to bind events in javascript end.

check the following snippet.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var mid = document.getElementById("mid");
  mid.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editevent(this);
  })
}

function editevent(thisObj) {

  var id = thisObj.getAttribute('id');
  var dataniq = thisObj.getAttribute('data-niq');
  alert(id);
  alert(dataniq);
}
```

```html
<button id="mid" data-niq="niq" class="mr edit btn btn-success pull-right">Edit</button>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect answer. Here is a reference on why inline javascript is bad most of the time: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Answer (score 1):

you have added this.id.getAttribute('data-niq');

remove id

```
this.getAttribute('data-niq')
```